# php syntax error when calling mysqli_query, how to format and execute sql commands via php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax

```
<?php include 'functions.php'; ?>

<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","XXX","XXX","XXX");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>

<?php

$ret=standings();
$count=count($ret['position']);


$sql = "INSERT INTO `bryan_wrdp1`.`btb_picks` (`position`, `golfer_name`, `round_1`, `round_2`, `round_3`, `round_4`, `today`, `through`, `total`, `strokes`, `player_name`, `pick_no`) VALUES (\'1\', \'b\', \'5\', \'5\', \'5\', \'5\', \'-8\', \'f\', \'44\', \'44\', \'\', \'\');"

mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home1/bryan/public_html/golf/leaderboard_v2.php on line 26

Why does this line produce a syntax error? How should it be formatted?

This line works just fine:

```
mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM `btb_picks`;") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: For one thing, this `mysql_error` must be `mysqli_error` you can't mix those two function types. Plus, your quote is misplaced which should read as `)";` I've seen this code before, btw. Too many things wrong with your code.

Comment: -1. I see no line 26 in the present code.

Answer (score 0):

you have missed semicolon in the end of this line:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `bryan_wrdp1`.`btb_picks` (`position`, `golfer_name`, `round_1`, `round_2`, `round_3`, `round_4`, `today`, `through`, `total`, `strokes`, `player_name`, `pick_no`) VALUES (\'1\', \'b\', \'5\', \'5\', \'5\', \'5\', \'-8\', \'f\', \'44\', \'44\', \'\', \'\');"
```

and do not need `\` in the string since you have been using single quotes inside double quotes.

try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `bryan_wrdp1`.`btb_picks` (`position`, `golfer_name`, `round_1`, `round_2`, `round_3`, `round_4`, `today`, `through`, `total`, `strokes`, `player_name`, `pick_no`) VALUES ('1', 'b', '5', '5', '5', '5', '-8', 'f', '44', '44', '\', '\');";
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put slashes 
 Change it to :

```
INSERT INTO `bryan_wrdp1`.`btb_picks` (`position`, `golfer_name`, `round_1`, `round_2`, `round_3`, `round_4`, `today`, `through`, `total`, `strokes`, `player_name`, `pick_no`) VALUES ('1', 'b', '5', '5', '5', '5', '-8', 'f', '44', '44', '', '');
```

Comment: Won't the slashes be necessary for situations where entries include characters  (')  that need to be escaped? This is the case on my full data set.